# how to identify received connection is v4 or v6 if server is listening on v6 socket with IPV6_V6 option set to false

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, ipv6, ipv4

I have created a v6 socket with socket option ipv6_v6only set to false. I am able to accept connections now from both v4 client and v6 client. Further i wanted to add some option to the socket like MD5 hash and also converting address to presentable format so i wanted to know if there is any way to identify whether received connection is v4 or v6 based on the below code.

Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define MAX 80
#define PORT 8085
#define SA struct sockaddr

// Function designed for chat between client and server.
void func(int sockfd)
{
    char buff[MAX];
    int n;
    // infinite loop for chat
    for (;;) {
        bzero(buff, MAX);

        // read the message from client and copy it in buffer
        read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
        // print buffer which contains the client contents
        printf("From client: %s\t To client : ", buff);
        bzero(buff, MAX);
        n = 0;
        // copy server message in the buffer
        while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n')
            ;

        // and send that buffer to client
        write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
        // if msg contains "Exit" then server exit and chat ended.
        if (strncmp("exit", buff, 4) == 0) {
            printf("Server Exit...\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Driver function
int main()
{
    int sockfd, connfd, len;
    struct sockaddr_in6 servaddr;
    struct sockaddr_in cli;
    int ret, flag;
    pid_t childpid;

    // socket create and verification
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        perror("socket()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");

    /* Set socket to reuse address */
    flag = 1;
    ret = setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &flag, sizeof(flag));
    if(ret == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR)");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Set socket to reuse address */
    flag = 0;
    ret = setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &flag, sizeof(flag));
    if(ret != 0) {
        perror("setsockopt(IPV6_V6ONLY)");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    // assign IP, PORT
    servaddr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    servaddr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    servaddr.sin6_port = htons(PORT);

    // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification
    ret = bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    if (ret == -1) {
        printf("socket bind failed...\n");
        perror("listen()");
        close(sockfd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully binded..\n");

    // Now server is ready to listen and verification
    if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0) {
        printf("Listen failed...\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
        printf("Server listening..\n");

    for (;;) { //infinite loop
            len = sizeof(cli);
            // Accept the data packet from client and verification
            connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&cli, &len);
            if (connfd < 0) {
                printf("server accept failed...\n");
                perror("accept()");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            printf("Connection accepted...\n");

            *** 
             * Here i want to differentiate if the received connection is v4 or v6 and
             * based on that i want to do some operation like converting the client
             * address to presentable format, also applying md5 hash to the session
             ***
            if ( AF_INET ) {
                char str_addr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN] = {0};
                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(cli.sin_addr), str_addr, sizeof(str_addr));
                printf("New connection from: %s:%d ...\n", str_addr, ntohs(cli.sin_port));
            } else if ( AF_INET6 ) {
                char str_addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {0};
                inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(cli.sin6_addr), str_addr, sizeof(str_addr));
                printf("New connection from: %s:%d ...\n", str_addr, ntohs(cli.sin_port));
            }
                    
            if ((childpid = fork()) == 0) { //creating a child process

                    close(sockfd);
                    //stop listening for new connections by the main process.
                   //the child will continue to listen.
                    //the main process now handles the connected client.

                    // Function for chatting between client and server
                    func(connfd);

            }
            // After chatting close the socket
            close(connfd);
    }
}
```

Comment: `read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));`?  And how do you plan on handling a `read()` that reads less than `sizeof(buff)` bytes?  I suggest you create a reliable program before you try making it complicated.

Comment: `if ( AF_INET ) ...` is always going to be true.

Comment: If you use `getnameinfo()` to convert a sockaddr to a human-readable address, it handles all the different protocols transparently so you don't have to worry about them, btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an IPv6 socket, the local and remote address will always be of type `struct sockaddr_in6`, so your use of `sockaddr_in` (and likewise `sin_port` member) is wrong. Receiving IPv4 connections on a v6 listening socket happens with [v4-mapped addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses). The `IN6_IS_ADDR_V4MAPPED` macro from `netinet/in.h` can be used to query whether the `sin6_addr` (note the 6!) of the client address is a v4-mapped address from a connection that's v4 over the wire.

However, as Shawn noted in a comment:

> If you use `getnameinfo()` to convert a sockaddr to a human-readable address, it handles all the different protocols transparently so you don't have to worry about them, btw

you probably don't have reason to actually care. If you use the modern API for converting between `sockaddr` objects and strings, everything just automatically works and you never have to inspect the members of specific-family `sockaddr` structures.

Comment: Modified "cli" declaration to struct sockaddr_in6 and tried 
getnameinfo((SA*)&cli, len, node, NI_MAXHOST, serv, NI_MAXSERV, NI_NUMERICSERV );
It did work to get IP Address of v4 and v6 client and v4 client address is coming in v4-mapped format.
Thanks.

Comment: Further is there a way to know if the received connection is v4 or v6 ?